# How to read Sentinel-2 data in R

Tags: r

I want to classify Sentinel-2 data using ANN. If anyone knows how to do it in R. Please let's me know

```
df<-read.csv(file.choose())

head(df)
```

Comment: You should atleast show what your data looks like, what is the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to read data in R

Set working directory before running this code

```
Sentinel<-list.files(pattern = "tif$",full.names = T)

Sentinel<-stack(Sentinel)

# Check the data

head(Sentinel)

Sentinel
```